# Can I send a React component to the client while doing Server Side Rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I have a Reactjs application built on a Node/Express server. I am doing server side rendering via something like:

route.js

```
var Group = require('./react/component/groups');
var props = {foo: 'bar'};
var groupHtml = React.renderToString(Group(props));
  res.render('index.ejs', {
    reactOutput: groupHtml,
    jsonProps: JSON.stringify(props),
    start: 'lessonlist'
  });
```

index.ejs

```
<div id="react-main-mount"><%- reactOutput %></div>

<script id="props" type="application/json"><%- jsonProps %></script>
<script src="/js/<%= start %>.js"></script>
```

This works really great! But here is my problem:
One of my pages/components will have a **child component**. But this **child component** can be one of 50+ different components.

I assume I could **Require** every single component, even though only one will be used. This seems like a bad idea since my main.js file will be huge.

I tried sending it via a prop and JSON.stringify. This works on the server rendering to HTML, but this doesn't work on the client side because JSON.stringify can't stringify a react component.

I though I might be able to do an API call and return it, but same problem as above.

Is there any way to dynamically require something, say based off a variable like require('components/' + this.props.foo) **after** the I've browserified/reactified?

Any suggestions/answers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe one of these help? https://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-javascript-with-react-node/ https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Comment: `var dyn=require('path/'+name);` and later: `<dyn ...... />`?

Answer (score 0):

Browserify had always been too bulky for me, so I did my research and found [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). It allowed me to require other files on the client just like how Node does it.

It was difficult for me to get started with Require, but once I got it working, everything just seemed easier. See this [example](https://github.com/ben-z/react-starter-coffee-tutorial) I wrote in CoffeeScript.

Remember to have below code at the top of every isomorphic component so you don't stumble upon the problem I had with Node not understanding the keyword `define`.

```
if typeof define != 'function'
  define = require('amdefine')(module)

define (require) ->
```

Above code is written in coffeescript.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) allows you to do asynchronous bundle loading. This is intended for single page applications, where you don't want to have to include all of your javascript files until the user actually navigates to the *"page"* where they're needed. This allows you to fetch javascript with ajax dynamically. Check out the section titled **9. Async loading** in this [wonderful guide to Webpack](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto)

The implementation looks something like this...

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/feed') {
 showLoadingState();
 require.ensure([], function() { // this syntax is weird but it works
   hideLoadingState();
    require('./feed').show(); // when this function is called, the module is guaranteed to be synchronously available.
  });
} else if (window.location.pathname === '/profile') {
  showLoadingState();
  require.ensure([], function() {
    hideLoadingState();
    require('./profile').show();
  });
}
```

If you don't want to use Webpack, you could potentially just fetch the components with ajax as plain text and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it upon arrival. This is essentially what the browser is doing with script tags under the hood.